# Node.js showing on localhost but not on http on same machine

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a simple node.js server which shows index.html. When I run it on localhost it shows the page but when I try to run it on http:ip:8000 it says "This web page is not available".

This is my code:

```
    // server2.js (Express 4.0)
var express        = require('express');
var morgan         = require('morgan');
var bodyParser     = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var app            = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser());                      // pull information from html in POST
app.use(methodOverride());                  // simulate DELETE and PUT


var router = express.Router();

var notes = [
  {username: 'Mohit1406', password: 'midkm' ,firstName: 'mxkz', lastName: 'ckzmk', dob: '1994-05-08', gender: 'male'},
];

router.get('/note', function(req, res) {
  res.send(notes);
});
router.post('/note', function(req, res) {
  var note = req.body;
  notes.push(note);
  res.send(note);
});

app.use('/api', router);


app.listen(8000,'0.0.0.0');
console.log('Open http://localhost:8000 to access the files now');          // shoutout to the user
```

Comment: have you tried binding the app to the IP directly instead of useing the 0.0.0.0?

Comment: It's weird when I connected to HP network, it is working fine but when I connect to different network it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe a firewall is blocking the connections.

Comment: Which firewall it works on HP but even not on mobile hotspot

Comment: Internet Protocol version 6?

Comment: fe80:bc5f:4af2:3bd:b56b%15

Answer (score 0):

```
app.listen(8000);
```

hostname is optional

**server.listen(port, [hostname], [backlog], [callback])**#

> Begin accepting connections on the specified port and hostname. If the
>   hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections directed to
>   any IPv4 address (INADDR_ANY).

Comment: I am including 0.0.0.0 so that I can access that through any device in the same LAN

Comment: 0.0.0.0 - cover all ip's not only in LAN - which assigned with computer's network interfaces - the same as no hostname